# Texture atlas UV Mapped in Blender hitting performance hard

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm creating a scene where I have many exhibition stands with different brand logos on them. These, combined, are loaded in as one object which is exported from blender. Rather than having many server calls for these separate brand logos, I created a texture atlas and have mapped the correct parts to each surface within Blender.

This seemed like a great idea at the time, however, when loaded into three.js, it seems this large texture file (.jpg, 2856 × 2416, 200KB) is causing a drastic performance hit. Rather, a total meltdown.

Is there something I have done wrong in mapping this texture, or perhaps something I have not done in blender that is causing this issue? If not what what is the best way for me to proceed and get this working?

Comment: are you using the webgl renderer or canvas ?

Comment: I'm using webGL but have identified the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had not actually joined all of the objects into one object, so I'm guessing there were dozens of versions of the texture in the video ram instead of just one.

Answer (score 2):

Try making your texture a power of two, so try 2048x2048 and see how it compares.

*edit*

Also the texture is more like 20mb in the video memory.

Comment: As per my own answer just now, i'v sorted this issue but I haven't tried implementing the power of 2 suggestion. I believe it will improve performance as I have come across that before.